# What is the best way to organize Rspec tests when a Model interacts with a model of another class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

For the sake of argument, say I have an `Event` model that needs to a create a `Notification` when the `Event` is first created. E.g using the `after_create` callback in Rails.

In which spec should I place the tests for the callback? E.g `models/event_spec.rb`? `models/notification_spec.rb`? Somewhere else as an integration test?

Here’s my current thought process:

My first reaction was to place this in the `event_spec.rb`:

```
describe Event do
  ...
  describe 'callbacks' do
    it 'should create a Notification when first saved' do
      # assertions here
    end
  end
end
```

However this felt like I was breaking separation of concerns. E.g I’m testing that a `Notifcation` is created in the `Event` spec. I then thought it might be more appropriate to place these tests in  `notification_spec.rb`:

```
describe Notification do
  ...
  describe 'callbacks' do
   it 'should be created when new an Event is first saved' do
     # assertions here
   end
  end
end
```

But this doesn’t feel right either, as we’re now testing the callback code of the `Event` class in the `Notification` spec.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This belongs in the `Event` spec. The `Event` is responsible for creating the `Notification`. Also, the code for the callback is in the `Event` source file, so someone looking for the callback test would normally expect to find it in the `Event` spec.

The more important question is: how to test it? A '[mockist](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)' would isolate the `Notification` model completely:

```
it "should create a Notification" do
  Notification.should_receive(:create)
  event.save!
end
```

This ensures that the callback creates the `Notification`, but does not run the create method.

Comment: That's what I was leaning towards as well. I like the use of `should_receive`!